# Symfony using different doctrine fixture for different environments (prod, test, dev)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

Hi I have a question with using dataFixtures, I want to use fixtures for environments prod, dev, test. I have tried to use `--fixtures` option but it is a not found option.
How can I load my fixtures on command line with the file I want ?

Is it possible to do that using the `--env` option of `doctrine:fixtures:load` command?

I have fixtures on

- App/DataFixtures/Prod
- App/DataFixtures/Dev
- App/DataFixtures/Test

I'm using symfony 3.4
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `--fixtures` option has been removed in DoctrineFixturesBundle 3.0, the problem is about to be solved with a different [approach](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/219) using "sets". The solution seems to has been implemented but not yet been merged in the DoctrineFixturesBundle master.

I would suggest some patience at the time.

> **EDIT**: How to use environments to overcome this problem:

As asked in your comment, you can indeed use env option to overcome this problem like this:

At first you should create an abstract Fixture class which should live in your DataFixtures directory, with the container injected so that you can get the current environment from the kernel:

```
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

abstract class AbstractFixture implements ContainerAwareInterface, FixtureInterface
{
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
    
        $kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');

        if (in_array($kernel->getEnvironment(), $this->getEnvironments())) {
            $this->doLoad($manager);
        }
    }

    abstract protected function doLoad(ObjectManager $manager);

    abstract protected function getEnvironments();
}
```

Then you should extend this abstract Fixture class with your a class for each environment (prod, test, dev) like this (example shown only for prod):

```
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class ProdFixture extends AbstractFixture
{

    protected function doLoad(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // load what you need to load for prod environment 
    }

    protected function getEnvironments()
    {
        return ['prod'];
    }
 }
```

These `ProdFixture`, `TestFixture`, `DevFixture` etc. class should also live in your DataFixtures directory.

With this setup every time you run the `doctrine:fixtures:load` command with `--env` option, all Fixture classes will initially load (except the AbstractFixture class) but only the Fixture classes with the corresponding environment set in getEnvironments() will really executed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have seen --env in the list of option I don't know how to use it and if it's a solution ?

Comment: Edited my answer to explain how to use --env option for this reason.

Comment: I have reproduce same method but when i use doctrine:fixtures:load --env=prod, i have an error  'There are no commands defined in the "doctrine:fixtures" namespace. ' if i remove the --env option the command work :(

Comment: sorry i think it's because the bundle is register for dev and test on appKernel

Comment: A little bonus question :) in --env=dev it load DevFixture and ProdFixture ok but i have some reference in dev file to fixture on prod file ($this->getReference()) failed

Answer (score 2):

Symfony introduced the notion of "Group" in the fixture bundle. You can now group your fixtures by environment for example.

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-fixturesbundle-group-your-fixtures